# Will repositioning a CALayer automatically move the sublayers inside it?

Tags: ios, calayer

I have a bunch of custom CALayers being added on my MPMoviePlayer and whenever I resize it or move it. The sublayers remain on the same location on the screen.

The solution I used here was to reposition all the CALayer's again when the Player is resized or moved.

But now the requirement has slightly changed and I need to add a big Custom Layer on the player of the same size and then add custom sublayers to it.

now if I just reposition the Layer, will the sublayers also be repositioned ?

Comment: Can you use `UIViews` with `autoresizingMask` set instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the percent layer, sublayers will move with it. But I am not sure for resizing.

Have also a look at [layoutSublayers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/layoutSublayers) method. It allows you to layout the sublayers as you want.